# Can't figure out a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I have this piece of code to calculate first and second derivatives of a function at a given point

```
def yy(x):
   return 1.0*x*x

def d1(func, x ,e):
    x = x
    y = func(x)
    x1 = x + e
    y1 = func(x1)
    return 1.0*(y - y1)/(x - x1)

def d2(func ,x, e):
    x = x
    y = d1(func, x, e)
    x1 = x + e
    y1 = d1(func, x1, e)
    return 1.0*(y - y1)/(x - x1)
```

yy is the actual function. d1 and d2 functions that calculate the 1st and 2nd derivatives. They are the ones I'm interested in optimizing. As you can see they both have almost the same code. I could basically keep writing functions like that for 3rd, 4th, etc derivatives, however I'm wondering if it is possible to write it as a single function specifying the derivative level as a parameter.

Comment: These aren't derivatives but difference quotients. Your `e` is usually called `h` in math books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def deriv(func, order, x, e):
    if order < 0: raise ValueError
    if order == 0: return func(x)
    y = deriv(func, order-1, x, e)
    x1 = x + e
    y1 = deriv(func, order-1, x1, e)
    return float(y - y1)/(x - x1)
```

order = 1 gives the first derivative, order = 2 gives the 2nd, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, where lvl is derivative level.

```
def d(func, x ,e, lvl):
    x1 = x + e

    if lvl == 1:
        x = x
        y = func(x)
        y1 = func(x1)
        return 1.0*(y - y1)/(x - x1)
    else:
        return 1.0*(d(func, x, e, lvl-1) - d(func, x1, e, lvl-1) )/(x-x1)
```

Comment: Anubhav's solution is superior to yours. Your solution can't handle `lvl=0`, and your `lvl=1` case is somehow one iteration 'unrolled' in the sense that for example, you had to write the formula 1.0*(...)/(...) in both cases.

Comment: I agree -- I tried to just reuse the code from d1 and d2 from original question instead of writing a new function.  Anubhav's solution is better.